# How do I find the best fit line which passes through a series of data?

Tags: fitting, interpolation

I have a list of data and want to create a function which passes through them.

I'm new to Mathematica and don't know how to do this work.

Could anyone explain this topic with fitting the below data?

Here is a sample of my data.

```
{9.28188, 9.28188, 9.28188, 9.28188, 9.28188, 9.28188, 9.28391, 
 9.29315, 9.30736, 9.32627, 9.34909, 9.37394, 9.39704, 9.41008, 
 9.41007, 9.41007, 9.41007, 9.41007, 9.41007, 9.41007, 9.41007, 
 9.41007, 9.41007, 9.41007, 9.41007}
```

Comment: I've given a good explanation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/7129), but here is the gist: use fitting if your data have experimental error in them, and use interpolation if you are sure all those numbers are correct.

Comment: `blendFun[n_, nblend_, nexp_, offset_, gain_] := 
 offset - gain ((nblend/n)^nexp - (n/nblend)^nexp)/((nblend/n)^
       nexp + (n/nblend)^nexp)`; `nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  blendFun[n, nblend, nexp, offset, 
   gain],  {{nblend, 11}, {nexp, 5}, {offset, 9.41}, {gain, 0.13}}, n]`;

Comment: @JackLaVigne, Thanks for your reply, but your response is very advanced! Is there any another simple procedure?  I can't figure out the logic of your solution. May i find a continuous function instead of discontinuous one?

Comment: @JackLaVigne I sent an e-mail with ID: ali.nematy@gmail.com. Thanks